# Code is not executing within Javascript module typed script source [ES6]

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, module

Trying to use ES6 but I'm stuck on something.
To make it simple there is two problems :

1. JS source code is not executed within a script called with `module="type"` HTMLelements
2. importing directly from index.html returns `SyntaxError: fields are not currently supported`

Tried and dug both cases, can't get what is wrong. Paths are right.
Not putting `.js` extension within `from` statement was returning errors for the second try with import used directly in `index.html`.
Previously `initGame()` was a `$(document).ready(function(e) { ... });`.
Also returns an error, if I don't sepcify `type="module"` within `index.html`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">

  <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="design/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <main id="displayer">
  </main>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  import { initGame } from "./lib/js/core.js";
  initGame();
</script>
<script type="application/javascript, module" src="./lib/js/core.js"></script>
</html>
```

```js
//core.js
import { Board } from './classes/Board.js';
import { Pawn } from './classes/Pawn.js';

export function initGame () {
  console.log("plop");
  var $displayer = $('#displayer');
  var board = new Board($displayer, 32, 19, 19, ['#ffffcc', '#333333']);
  console.debug(board);
}
```

```js
//Board.js
import { TileMap } from "./TileMap.js"

export class Board extends TileMap
{
    _tileColors;

    constructor(wrapper, tileSize, columnsNb, rowsNb, tileColors) {
        super(wrapper, tileSize, columnsNb, rowsNb);

        this._name = "Board:" + columnsNb + ":" + rowsNb;

        this.selector.css({
            class: "board"
        })

        tileColors.forEach(function(color, i) {
            this._tileColors[i] = color;
        });
        this.colorize();
    }

    colorize() {
        this._grid.forEach(function(col, i) {
            col.forEach( function(tile, j) {
                tile.color = ((i + j) % 2 === 0) ? this.getColor(0) : this.getColor(1);
            });
        });
    }

    getColor(index) {
        return this._tileColors[index];
    }
}
```

Just wanting to use the modulare system of ES6 for convenience and self teaching.

Errors:

1. If no `type="module" src="path"` specified:

   - `SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`
2. empty console if just `<script type="module">` and `$(document).ready()` variation for `core.js`
3. If this version is active:

   - `SyntaxError: fields are not currently supported`

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript compiler? And can you copy some of the errors that you got.

Comment: Nope I'm not. Is it needed ?
I'll had them to the main post.

Comment: Does the JavaScript file load when you do `import { initGame } from "./lib/js/core.js";` in the inline `<script>`? Check your browser's network tab.

Comment: only the `GET` from jquery, but still returning the third error :
[screenshot](https://zupimages.net/up/19/07/gouo.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax you used to declare `_tileColors` is called a [field declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations) and is a highly experimental proposal. They were only implemented in Chrome 72 and above, and seem to be partially implemented in some Firefox builds if you enable the experimental flag for them.

You need to remove the line `_titleColors;` from the class and to set `this._titleColors` within the constructor. Besides, your constructor's code as it stands is broken, it's trying to set the content of `_titleColors` but the variable isn't even initialized. Instead, you can do (assuming titleColors is an array):

```
// create an array copy of titleColors
this._tileColors = [...titleColors];
```